# I get ArgumentException while comparing two strings

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, backend

This is my code

```cs
public async Task<bool> GetSearchDuplicateTitleAsync(string title)
{
     try
      { 
        bool result = true;
        var filter = Builders<ApiLibraryModel>.Filter.Where(x => x.ApiName.ToLower().
                  Replace(" ",string.Empty).Contains(title.ToLower().
                  Replace(" ",string.Empty)));
        var newfilter = await _repository._apiLibrary.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
        if (newfilter.Count() > 0)
        {
            result=false;
        }
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

And this is the error that I am getting:

```
"ArgumentException: Unsupported filter: {document}{ApiName}.ToLower()
.Replace(" ", "").Contains("applicationtest")."
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Presumably you're doing a query to a database/data store here? If so, the query engine likely can't interpret filters containing C# method calls. Do the normalization (i.e. the lower case and the replace) outside of the filter, and then see if it works with just a `Contains()`.

Comment: the mongodb c# driver does not have support for translating `Replace(" ",string.Empty)` to mongo query language. your best bet is to store another field called `ApiNameNormalized` with pre lowercased+whitespace stripped value.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see original source code of your library

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver/Linq/Translators/PredicateTranslator.cs#L141

The cause is

```
filter == null
```

The filter was null is

```cs
{document}{ApiName}.ToLower().Replace(" ", "").Contains("applicationtest")
```